# UIButton to hide UIview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a button in a UIview (includes TextView and an a button). No problem unhiding it with a button in the view controller. The hide button though is not working. It is the IBAction. It was (UIButton *) earlier but also tried the (id) just to check. The button has no response at all. Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)shortDesc:(UIButton *)sender {
[self.shortDescView setHidden:NO];
[self shortDecChange];
}

- (IBAction)hideShorDescView:(id)sender {
[self.shortDescView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: is it connected properly? check in your storyboard/xib

Comment: Yes mate, in touchDown event. I was thinking will it be a problem that I am using something in the UIView that I am also using to hide it?

Comment: well... there doesn't seem to be any problem in the code. Also... using `id` or `UIButton *` doesn't matter which one **you** go for. Try putting a breakpoint on every `self.shortDescView setHidden:` line and check when and in which order these flow

Comment: right click on view controller and provide screenshot... this will help us to see whether button are connected properly or not...

Comment: This is Objective-C.  Not C or C++ or any other language.  We don't give our methods or variables weird, cryptic abbreviated names.

Comment: Can you at least confirm via breakpoint or NSLog statement that the methods are at least being called?

Comment: note taken on the not abbreviated.

Comment: Of all the buttons, it is the only one without referenced outlet. Isn't writing the code in the code in the -(IBAction)myMethod automatically connects them?

Comment: Actually NSLog is one gof my problems. I have tried all suggestions ion how to open it but still does not appear. .

Comment: When I hide a view, do I need to hide all of the components individually? Like I only hide the View, where the textview and exit button resides.

Comment: Sorry, i cannot upload an image yet. (reputation needed) but would it be the "no referencing outlet" that is giving the problem? as said earlier, shouldn't it be automatically added as I have it in the IBAction code?

Comment: No! it will not be automatically connected. Try some tutorials here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: @user3623052 : upload the image to tinypic / imageshack or any similar service and post the image link in your question. Also, just by specifying `IBAction` or `IBOutlet`, objects don't get automatically connected. hm... ok, check this: On the left of `IBAction`, if you [see a dot](http://www.codigator.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/51.jpg) with a hollow inside then you know that the method is not connected via the IB.

Comment: Thanks all. I have removed the new IBActions and Outlets and reconnected them. Worked well. Lots of lesson learned from this post especially how to get a negative vote. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

- First Make sure you have connections right on `UIButton` & `UIView`
- Check if `UIButton` Action calls or not by placing break point

Here is UIButton method should be :

```
-(IBAction)doAction:(id)sender
{
    [yourview setHidden:TRUE];
}
```

- Once its confirmed that your Method is working properly than above method will give you result for sure.

Hope it'll help you.